# MyBatis generator introduces newlines in function signatures

Tags: java, mybatis-generator

Using mybatis generator for classes of db tables, I found that sometimes it introduces newlines into function signatures in the .java files generated, *Example.java and *Mapper.java.

Can this be avoided someway, as it makes very difficult sometimes to check svn modifications?

I used the following configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE generatorConfiguration PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD MyBatis Generator Configuration 1.0//EN" "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-generator-config_1_0.dtd" >
<generatorConfiguration >
    <classPathEntry location="myFolder/myDriver.jar"/>

  <context id="MyDB" targetRuntime="MyBatis3">
    <commentGenerator>
        <property name="suppressDate" value="true" />
    </commentGenerator>
    <jdbcConnection driverClass="myDriver" connectionURL="myUrl" userId="myUserID" password="myPwd" />
    <javaModelGenerator targetPackage="myPackage" targetProject="myProject" >
       <property name="enableSubPackages" value="false" />
    </javaModelGenerator>
    <sqlMapGenerator targetPackage="myMapper" targetProject="myProject">
       <property name="enableSubPackages" value="false" />
    </sqlMapGenerator>
    <javaClientGenerator targetPackage="myMapper" targetProject="myProject" type="XMLMAPPER">
       <property name="enableSubPackages" value="false" />
    </javaClientGenerator>
    <table schema="MY_SCHEMA" tableName="TABLE_TO_GENERATE">
    </table>
  </context>
</generatorConfiguration>
```